# TickSpec: How do I use the same step name in different features?

Tags: testing, f#, bdd

I am fiddling around with the [Gilded Rose kata](https://github.com/NotMyself/GildedRose) in F#. I am writing my tests in [TickSpec](https://tickspec.codeplex.com/) and [FsUnit](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsUnit) so that they essentially mirror [Jim Weirich's Gilded Rose tests](https://github.com/jimweirich/gilded_rose_kata/blob/master/gilded_rose_spec.rb) written in [RSpec](http://rspec.info/).

When I run them in Visual Studio's Test Explorer, I get the following error:

```
Ambiguous step definition
(AgedBrieSpecs.I update the quality|NormalItemSpecs.I update the quality)
on line 5 in Feature: Aged Brie quality updates  
    "When I update the quality"
```

Basically, I'm trying to use the same function name in different features. But they are in different modules. I could even put them in different namespaces, but that doesn't help either.

So then, how do I use step names that happen to be the same, but in different features? Am I just "doing it wrong"?

My feature text and counterpart F# code is as follows:

**NormalItemFeature.txt:**

```
Feature: Normal item quality updates

Scenario 1: Each day the sell-in value decreases by one
    Given a normal item with a sell-in value of 10
    When I update the quality
    Then its sell-in value should be 9
```

**AgedBrieFeature.txt:**

```
Feature: Aged Brie quality updates

Scenario 1: Each day the sell-in value decreases by one
    Given Aged Brie with a sell-in value of 10
    When I update the quality
    Then its sell-in value should be 9
```

**NormalItemSpec.fs:**

```ml
module GildedRoseCsSpecs.NormalItemSpecs

open FsUnit
open TickSpec
open System.Linq
open GildedRoseCs

let mutable rose = GildedRose([].ToList())
let item = Item(Name = "Normal Item", SellIn = 10, Quality = 5)

let [<Given>] ``a normal item with a sell-in value of (\d+)`` (sellIn : int) =
    item.SellIn <- sellIn

let [<When>] ``I update the quality`` () =
    rose <- GildedRose([item].ToList())
    rose.UpdateQuality()

let [<Then>] ``its sell-in value should be (\d+)`` (sellIn : int) =
    rose.Items.First().SellIn |> should equal sellIn
```

**AgedBrieSpecs.fs:**

```ml
module GildedRoseCsSpecs.AgedBrieSpecs

open FsUnit
open TickSpec
open System.Linq
open GildedRoseCs

let mutable rose = GildedRose([].ToList())
let item = Item(Name = "Aged Brie", SellIn = 10, Quality = 5)

let [<Given>] ``Aged Brie with a sell-in value of (\d+)`` (sellIn : int) =
    item.SellIn <- sellIn

let [<When>] ``I update the quality`` () =
    rose <- GildedRose([item].ToList())
    rose.UpdateQuality()

let [<Then>] ``its sell-in value should be (\d+)`` (sellIn : int) =
    rose.Items.First().SellIn |> should equal sellIn
```

And finally, I have the following lines in my **Fixtures.fs** file:

```ml
// FeatureFixture definition omitted for brevity

type NormalItemFeature () = inherit FeatureFixture("NormalItemFeature.txt")
type AgedBrieFeature () = inherit FeatureFixture("AgedBrieFeature.txt")
```

P.S. Yes, I understand that there is a **lot** of duplication here that could be consolidated. While this is a contrived example, I can imagine that two entirely different features could have steps with the same descriptive text. It seems to me that TickSpec ought to be able to handle such name collisions.

Comment: I suppose what you're looking for is the StepScope attribute - take a look here: http://www.trelford.com/blog/post/Step.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @scrwtp! The [`StepScope` attribute](http://www.trelford.com/blog/post/Step.aspx) is what I was looking for.

The only downside is that I have to decorate every function. I cannot seem to attach one `StepScope` attribute to a class (or some other grouping construct) and have TickSpec pick up all the `Given`|`When`|`Then`-tagged methods in that class to implement the steps in my feature. Nevertheless, it does deal with the problem of name collision.